# Inconsistency in required includes for extending classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, dev-c++

This is more a case of something was working when i feel like it shouldn't have been. I'm not quite sure if this falls under the usual purview of this site, but i'm rather curious about it so i figured that asking couldn't hurt.

Using dev-c++ IDE, i'm working on one of the ever-popular 'make an ATM program' projects in a tutorial. In it is the base Account class which has all the members and a set of virtual functions, and the Checking and Savings classes which are intended to extend it with functionality specific to those account types.

When i tried to implement Checking.h as so;

```
#ifndef CHECKING_H
#define CHECKING_H

class Checking : public Account
{
private:
...
```

it threw an "expected class name before {" error at line 5 (and an 'object not defined in scope' at every instance of Account::*, of course) until i included Account.h. However, this simple mistake took me a while to find because i was comparing the file to Savings.h, which compiled fine but doesn't seem to need the same include. The code above failed, but the set below is in it's own Savings.h, and seems to work fine:

```
#ifndef SAVINGS_H
#define SAVINGS_H

class Savings : public Account
{
protected:
...
```

So, i have all my classes as separate files in one directory, and two derived classes in my project. Both extend the same base class, both use its members, extend some of its functions, and directly call others, but only one needs the base class's .h included to compile. Any usual suspects as to why this would be?

Comment: `#include` basically does a copy paste. look through your project and work that out.

Answer (score 0):

A likely candidate for the problem is that you are compiling a file that looks something like this:

```
#include "Account.h"
#include "Savings.h"

...
```

Because "Account.h" is included before "Savings.h", the `Account` class definition is seen before the `Savings` class definition. So there is no problem. Or rather, the problem is hidden. "Savings.h" should still include "Account.h", even if the problem seems to disappear in some cases.

Comment: My main.cpp does have `#include "account.h"
#include "checking.h"
#include "savings.h"`?

Comment: @user3377275: Is that a question?

Comment: Half of one, sorry. Return didn't quite do what i expected.    Yes, i do have a file in the project whose header has those includes, but i have all three and checking.h is before savings.h on the list. I was curious if that altered your diagnosis at all, or if my compiler is simply moving in mysterious ways.

Comment: @user3377275: Are there any other files besides the four you've mentioned so far?

Comment: @Benjamin_Lindley some needed libraries - <fstream> and <stdio> - but no other files, no. Account, Checking, and Saving are all my classes at this stage in the tutorial.

Comment: @user3377275: So, there's no "Account.cpp" or "Savings.cpp" or "Checking.cpp" ? All the code is in the headers?

Comment: Ah, now i feel silly. I do have all those, and an #include "account.h" was hidden in savings.cpp. The very top line was off-screen, had to scroll up to see it. Thanks for patiently helping me find that, at any rate.